# Como escribo una list comprenhension de los cubos del 1 al 10 si el value***3 me da invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

```
cubes=[value***3 for value in range(1,10)]
print(cubes
```

Comment: No es `***` sino `**`, es decir `[value**3 for value in range(1,10)]`

Answer (score 2):

si lo que quieres es ver todos los números del 1 al 10 al cubo se debe hacer de esta forma

```
for num in range(1,11):
    print(f"{num} al cubo es: {num**3}")
```

para elevar un numero a n se debe usar dos veces el operador de multiplicación **

para almacenarlos en una lista lo podes hacer de la siguiente manera

```
cubes=[value**3 for value in range(1,11)]
print(cubes)
```

Comment: Graciassss espero que me puedan seguir ayudando

Comment: @LuisManuelDíazPérez si solucióne con éxito tu pregunta me servíria que selecciones el tick de mí respuesta así ya figura como finalizado

Comment: Buenas @LuisManuelDíazPérez . Eres nuevo en Stackoverflow y por eso posiblemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de darle las gracias a una persona, es puntuar positivamente la respuesta. Y porqué no, si hay varias y es la que más te a gustado, marcarla como pregunta correcta. Esto no solo es una forma de agredecer tu trabajo a aquellos que te han ayudado desinteresadamente, si no que servirá para posicionar mejor la pregunta, haciendo que personas con la misma duda, que tú, la encuentren y vean la solución! :)

Comment: @RubialesAlberto so soy nuevo. Lo único que necesito es llegar a 50 puntos para poder ayudar comentando el código del que pregunta. Para poder ayudarlo de una forma más cercana. Una vez llegue a 50 puntos solo me dedicare a ayudar no a pedir xp

Comment: Buenas @agustindamore ha habido una confusión. El comentario, como indico, es dirigido a LuisManuelDiazPerez . En el que le pido que mejor que darte las gracias, es puntuarte positivamente por tu buena respuesta. Basicamente estamos tu y yo indicandolé, lo mismo, que si la respuesta es buena, la puntue positivamente, no hay nada malo en indicar que te puntue positivamente la pregunta, si te han dado las gracias :)

Comment: Realmente no lo sabía. Ya lo hice. Gracias por informar

Comment: Muchas gracias chicos! A seguír ayudándonos codo a codo!

Answer (score 2):

En Python, el operador de potencia es el operador ****** (dos asteriscos, ver [The power operator](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/power.html)), por lo tanto, el código que tienes debería ser  de la siguiente forma:

```
cubes=[value**3 for value in range(1,10)]
print(cubes)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Fue de mucha ayuda

Comment: Buenas @LuisManuelDíazPérez . Eres nuevo en Stackoverflow y por eso posiblemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de darle las gracias a una persona, es puntuar positivamente la respuesta. Y porqué no, si hay varias y es la que más te a gustado, marcarla como **pregunta correcta**. Esto no solo es una forma de agredecer tu trabajo a aquellos que te han ayudado desinteresadamente, si no que servirá para posicionar mejor la pregunta, haciendo que personas con la misma duda, que tú, la encuentren y vean la solución! :)